# Bootstrap Issue: No Space Between Columns, Unwanted Extra Space between Footer and Section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a real estate website project. I have already created Photoshop template and uploaded it on Behance. 
https://www.behance.net/csc103falld848

Right now, I am creating the static version of the real estate store template.

I am facing an issue. I can't create a space between the columns. Also, there is a unwanted extra space between footer and section.

```css
  #properties-image {
        height: 25%;
    }
    
    #properties-list {
        background-color: #c0c0c0;
    }
    
    .property-list-container {
        padding-top: 20px;
        
        
        
    }
    
    #font-awesome-icons-store-first {
        float: left;
        
        
    }
    
    #font-awesome-icons-store {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        
    }
    
    #icon-store {
        margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    }
    
    #icon-value {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 2px;
    }
    
    .button-call{
        background-color: #464646;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 2px;
    }
    
    .button-email{
        background-color: #170b0b;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-left: 4px;
    }
    
    #column-margin-top {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    #properties-list {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .property-store-container {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /*-- //footer --*/
    
    #footer-real-estate{
        background-color: #464646;
        height: 15%;
        
    }
    
    #visit-our-store-heading, #contact-a-specialist-heading{
        color: #f5f5f5;
    }
```

```html
            <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
            <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            
            <!-- Custom CSS -->
      <link href="assets/css/dummy.css" rel="stylesheet">
      
      <!-- FontAwesome icon fonts -->
      <link href="assets/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      
      <!-- Google Fonts -->
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
            <!-- Custom Theme files -->
    <!--        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />-->
    <!--        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />-->
            <link href="css/fasthover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <link href="css/popuo-box.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <!-- //Custom Theme files -->
      
        
            <!-- Website Logo -->
        
            <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/KS%20Large.jpg">
        
            <!-- Animate.css -->
            <link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        

            <section id="properties-list" >
                <div class="container ">
                    <div class="property-list-container">
        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <img id="properties-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/9b/45/5b9b451db9428e06be9b3af900cfefc4.jpg">
                                    <h4>RM 1500</h4>
                                    <div id="property-content">
                                    Platinum Splendor, Putra Jaya Apartment<br>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store-first">    
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bed"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store"> 
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bath"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store">     
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-square"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <br>
                                    Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                                    <button class="button-call">Call</button>
                                    <button class="button-email">Email</button>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <img id="properties-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/9b/45/5b9b451db9428e06be9b3af900cfefc4.jpg">
                                    <h4>RM 1500</h4>
                                    <div id="property-content">
                                    Platinum Splendor, Putra Jaya Apartment<br>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store-first">    
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bed"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store"> 
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bath"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store">     
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-square"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <br>
                                    Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                                    <button class="button-call">Call</button>
                                    <button class="button-email">Email</button>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <img id="properties-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/9b/45/5b9b451db9428e06be9b3af900cfefc4.jpg">
                                    <h4>RM 1500</h4>
                                    <div id="property-content">
                                    Platinum Splendor, Putra Jaya Apartment<br>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store-first">    
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bed"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store"> 
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bath"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store">     
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-square"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <br>
                                    Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                                    <button class="button-call">Call</button>
                                    <button class="button-email">Email</button>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                
                                <div id="column-margin-top" class="col-sm-4">
                                    <img id="properties-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/9b/45/5b9b451db9428e06be9b3af900cfefc4.jpg">
                                    <h4>RM 1500</h4>
                                    <div id="property-content">
                                    Platinum Splendor, Putra Jaya Apartment<br>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store-first">    
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bed"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store"> 
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bath"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store">     
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-square"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <br>
                                    Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                                    <button class="button-call">Call</button>
                                    <button class="button-email">Email</button>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div id="column-margin-top" class="col-sm-4">
                                    <img id="properties-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/9b/45/5b9b451db9428e06be9b3af900cfefc4.jpg">
                                    <h4>RM 1500</h4>
                                    <div id="property-content">
                                    Platinum Splendor, Putra Jaya Apartment<br>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store-first">    
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bed"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store"> 
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bath"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store">     
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-square"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <br>
                                    Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                                    <button class="button-call">Call</button>
                                    <button class="button-email">Email</button>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div id="column-margin-top" class="col-sm-4">
                                    <img id="properties-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/9b/45/5b9b451db9428e06be9b3af900cfefc4.jpg">
                                    <h4>RM 1500</h4>
                                    <div id="property-content">
                                    Platinum Splendor, Putra Jaya Apartment<br>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store-first">    
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bed"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store"> 
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-bath"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div id="font-awesome-icons-store">     
                                    <i id="icon-store" class="fa fa-square"></i><div id="icon-value">3</div>
                                        </div>
                                    <br>
                                    Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                                    <button class="button-call">Call</button>
                                    <button class="button-email">Email</button>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
    <!--
                                <div id="column-margin-top" class="col-sm-4">
                                Pages
                                
                                </div>
                                
                                <div id="column-margin-top" class="col-sm-8">
                                <i class="fa fa-forward"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                                1  2  3  4  5
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-backward"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>    
                                
                                </div>
                                
    -->
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            
         
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        <aside class="col-sm-2">
                
                <br>
                
                <div id="rectangle">
                    
                    <div class="col-sm-4 search-rectangle" id="search-rectangle">
                        <i id="search" class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-sm-8" id="search-here-rectangle">
                        <input id="search-field" type="text" name="Search Here" value="Search Here" size="20">
                    </div>
                
                </div>
                
                <br>
                
                <br>
                
                <h3>Categories</h3>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Duplex">Duplex
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Duplex">Apartments
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Duplex">Townhouses
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Duplex">Detached Houses
                <br>
                More...
                
                
                
                <h3>Room</h3>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="1">1
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="2">2
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="3">3
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="4">4+
                <br>
                
                
        
                
                <h3>Bath</h3>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="1">1
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="2">2
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="3">3
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="4">4+
                <br>
                            
                <h3>Price</h3>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="1">RM 500 - RM 1000
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="2">RM 1000 - RM 1500
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="3">RM 1500 - RM 2000
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="4">RM 2000 - RM 2500
                <br>
                            
                <h3>Purpose</h3>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="1">Purchase
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="2">Rent
                
                
                
                
                
                
                </aside>
                        
                        
                </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
        
                
                <!-- FOOTER
      =================================================== -->
      <section id="footer-real-estate">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="no-1">
                                
                                <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">MENU</h4>
                                <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">BLOG / CONTACTS / AGENTS</h4>
                                
                                
                            </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="no-1">
                                
                                <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">CONTACT</h4>
                                <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">148, KUALA LUMPUR</h4>
                                <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">MALAYSIA</h4>
                                
                                
                            </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="no-1">
                                
                                <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">SOCIAL</h4>
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                                <h5 class="copy">&copy; Md. Ehsanul Haque Kanan</h5>
</div>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                </section>
```

Comment: You can't expect us to be able to help you, if you don't help us help you. You have given nearly 100% code, not shown us where the issue is. It's much easier if you'd show us a live version (link) of what you have done and pointed us in the direction of your issue with a code snippet - we'd be able to help.

Comment: @Lachie Do you want me to use codepen.io?

Comment: @Lachie Also,do you want me to give you an edited screenshot using paint that will point the exact issue with the arrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hve tried modified your structure a little. With this at least some basic structure of layout has been created. It's not complete, but contain a layout to be followed. Please go through with it, then you can add your extra elements too.

```css
#properties-image {
  height: 25%;
}

#properties-list {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

.property-list-container {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#font-awesome-icons-store-first {
  float: left;
}

#font-awesome-icons-store {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#icon-store {
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

#icon-value {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.button-call {
  background-color: #464646;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.button-email {
  background-color: #170b0b;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}

#column-margin-top {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* #properties-list {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
} */

.property-store-container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}


/*-- //footer --*/

#footer-real-estate {
  background-color: #464646;
  height: 15%;
}

#visit-our-store-heading,
#contact-a-specialist-heading {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container ">
  <div class="page-wrapper" style="
    /* padding: 20px; */
">
    <section id="properties-list">

      <div class="property-list-container" style="
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    padding: 40px;
">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img id="properties-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/9b/45/5b9b451db9428e06be9b3af900cfefc4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <h4>RM 1500</h4>
                <div id="property-content">

                  <p> Platinum Splendor, Putra Jaya Apartment</p>


                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> <i class="fa fa-search"> 3 </i></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> <i class="fa fa-search"> 3 </i></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> <i class="fa fa-search"> 3 </i></div>

                  </div>



                  <p> Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <button class="button-call">Call</button>
                    <button class="button-email">Email</button>
                  </div>
                </div>


              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img id="properties-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/9b/45/5b9b451db9428e06be9b3af900cfefc4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <h4>RM 1500</h4>
                <div id="property-content">

                  <p> Platinum Splendor, Putra Jaya Apartment</p>


                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> <i class="fa fa-search"> 3 </i></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> <i class="fa fa-search"> 3 </i></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> <i class="fa fa-search"> 3 </i></div>

                  </div>



                  <p> Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <button class="button-call">Call</button>
                    <button class="button-email">Email</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img id="properties-image" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/9b/45/5b9b451db9428e06be9b3af900cfefc4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <h4>RM 1500</h4>
                <div id="property-content">

                  <p> Platinum Splendor, Putra Jaya Apartment</p>


                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> <i class="fa fa-search"> 3 </i></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> <i class="fa fa-search"> 3 </i></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> <i class="fa fa-search"> 3 </i></div>

                  </div>



                  <p> Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <button class="button-call">Call</button>
                    <button class="button-email">Email</button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>









              <!--
                            <div id="column-margin-top" class="col-sm-4">
                            Pages

                            </div>

                            <div id="column-margin-top" class="col-sm-8">
                            <i class="fa fa-forward"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                            1  2  3  4  5
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-backward"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>    

                            </div>

-->






            </div>




          </div>

          <aside class="col-sm-2">

            <br>

            <div id="rectangle">

              <div class="col-sm-4 search-rectangle" id="search-rectangle">
                <i id="search" class="fa fa-search"></i>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-8" id="search-here-rectangle">
                <input id="search-field" type="text" name="Search Here" value="Search Here" size="20">
              </div>

            </div>

            <br>

            <br>

            <h3>Categories</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Duplex">Duplex
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Duplex">Apartments
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Duplex">Townhouses
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="categories" value="Duplex">Detached Houses
            <br> More...



            <h3>Room</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="1">1
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="2">2
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="3">3
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="4">4+
            <br>




            <h3>Bath</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="1">1
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="2">2
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="3">3
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="4">4+
            <br>

            <h3>Price</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="1">RM 500 - RM 1000
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="2">RM 1000 - RM 1500
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="3">RM 1500 - RM 2000
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="4">RM 2000 - RM 2500
            <br>

            <h3>Purpose</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="1">Purchase
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="2">Rent






          </aside>


        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
    <section id="footer-real-estate">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="no-1">

              <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">MENU</h4>
              <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">BLOG / CONTACTS / AGENTS</h4>


            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="no-1">

              <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">CONTACT</h4>
              <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">148, KUALA LUMPUR</h4>
              <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">MALAYSIA</h4>


            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="no-1">

              <h4 id="visit-our-store-heading">SOCIAL</h4>
              <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
              <h5 class="copy">© Md. Ehsanul Haque Kanan</h5>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </section>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- FOOTER
        =================================================== -->

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper">
  <div class="as-console"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue with the footer has been fixed. However, the issue with the columns are not fixed yet. Would you please take a look at this screenshot and provide fix for the specific issue? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U_l3ls4e7uxdJntDGL8dtts3zE3wHIjD

Comment: The answer is correct. But it hasn't fixed the issue fully. I am posting another question regarding the unsolved problem. There is no space between the columns.

Comment: Please add the link to another question you have posted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589410/bootstrap-button-issue-buttons-being-disorganized-unable-to-place-them-side-by#51589547

Comment: You have accepted an answer there, do you need some more help. Please confirm?

Comment: Yes, I have accepted the answer. Would you please help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591737/search-field-issue-cant-insert-search-field-side-by-side-with-the-search-font