# Search Field Issue: Can't Insert Search Field Side by Side with the Search Font Awesome Logo Properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a real estate website project. I have already created Photoshop template and uploaded it on Behance. https://www.behance.net/csc103falld848

Right now, I am creating the static version of the real estate store template. I am facing an issue. I can't insert search field side by side with the Search font awesome logo. I have tried my best to fix it. Please, take a look at the screen shot to understand the issue:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-wqJu9K6QtG1tzK_MiEuGAuveZ_-KKaK

```css
#search-rectangle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #0054a6;
}

#search-here-rectangle {
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}

#search-field {
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">

  <div class="col-sm-4 search-rectangle" id="search-rectangle">
    <i id="search" class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8" id="search-here-rectangle">
    <input id="search-field" type="text" name="Search Here" value="Search Here" size="20">
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is the CodePen.io link:
https://codepen.io/kanan292/pen/rrpegK

Looking forward to getting a great solution from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.. Change "GO" text with the icon you want.

```css
.input-group .btn {
  background-color: #0054a6;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border: 0 none;
  color: #fff;
}

#search-field {
  width: 110px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
  border: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container" style="
    margin-top: 20px;
">

  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" style="background-color: #0054a6;">Go!</button>
      </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." id="search-field" name="Search Here" value="Search Here">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are amazing! I am facing a slight issue with the navigation right now. If I can't fix it, I will post a new question about it. If possible, can you connect me on LinkedIn? You seem to be a passionate coder like me. So, I will love to get connected to you.